# How can i access my second class through the Main function?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have created two classes (Konto and Bank). I can access my first class (konto) through the main function but I can not access my second class (Bank) in order to set/change its values.

One of my friends told my that the problem is that I have my code in subfolders but I really do not know what it is and how I delete it.

So how can I access my second class(Bank) is my question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Konto {
public:
  int konto_nummer;
  std::string agare;
  double saldo;
  double rantesats;

public:
  Konto(int _nummer, std::string _agare, double _saldo, double _rantesats);
  int ge_konto_nummer();
  void ranteutbetalning(double r);
  //~konto();
  friend class Bank;
};

class Bank {
private:
  std::vector<Konto> konton;
  int antal_konton;
  int bank();

public:
  Bank(std::vector<Konto> _konton, int _antal_konton);
  void skrivut();
  //~Bank();
};

Bank::Bank(std::vector<Konto> _konton, int _antal_konton)
    : konton{_konton}, antal_konton{_antal_konton} {}

Konto::Konto(int _nummer = 12345, std::string _agare = "Ali",
             double _saldo = 500, double _rantesats = 0.07)
    : konto_nummer{_nummer}, agare{_agare}, saldo{_saldo}, rantesats{
                                                               _rantesats} {}

int Konto::ge_konto_nummer() { return konto_nummer; }

void Konto::ranteutbetalning(double r = 0.07) {
  rantesats = r;
  saldo += (rantesats * saldo);
}

void Bank::skrivut() {
  int choose;
  std::cout << "Choose: " << std::endl;
  std::cout << "1- Adda new account: " << std::endl;
  std::cout << "2-Print ur accounts: " << std::endl;
  std::cout << "3- Search for accounts: " << std::endl;
  std::cout << "4-Avsluta" << std::endl;
  std::cin >> choose;
}

int main() {
  Konto person;
  std::cout << "Account: " << person.konto_nummer << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Owner: " << person.agare << std::endl;
  std::cout << "saldo: " << person.saldo << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Rantesats: " << person.rantesats << std::endl;
  std::cout << "===============================" << std::endl;

  Bank obj;
  obj.skrivut();
}
```

Comment: Your `Bank` class does  not have a default constructor so `Bank obj;` is invalid.

Comment: What do you mean with `I can not access my second class (Bank) in order to set/change its values` do you get a compiler error? And if so, what error do you get?

Comment: Unrelated: I was wondering what exotic language you've used to name classes and variables until I realized it's my own language :-) Note: Replace "_4-Avsluta_" with "_4-Exit_" since the other options are in english. There are a few other places with language mixes too.

Comment: t.niese I get this error: no matching function for call to Bank::Bank

Comment: @KhanAli That's because of that Quimby mentioned in the first comment, but you have other errors to. You add default values for arguments in the member function definitions etc. Btw, why `Bank(std::vector<Konto> _konton, int _antal_konton);` instead of just `Bank(std::vector<Konto> _konton);` ? A `vector` has a `size()` function that returns the number of elements in the container.

Comment: It's not necessary to write ```private:```. By default every member of class is private.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the default constructor, hence the error;

```
error: no matching function for call to Bank::Bank
```

Just add this line:

```
public:
  Bank() {}    //add the default constructor
  Bank(std::vector<Konto> _konton, int _antal_konton);
```